# Large delay on switching directories in Dolphin

Tags: dolphin

I am using Debian testing with KDE and for a few weeks now (I assume it coincides with updates of Dolphin or other KDE libraries) every time I switch directories in Dolpin (21.08.2) there is a delay. It seems to be always roughly the same (nearly 1 second) no matter which directories I switch to.
To check if this is caused by my configuration, I created a new user, but there the same thing happens.

htop shows that dolphin is waiting on I/O (process status "D"), so I ran `strace -e openat dolphin`. Every time it is waiting I see output similar to this repeated around eight times.

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/blkid/blkid.tab", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/evms/volumes", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/lvm/VGs", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 23
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/devfs", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/devices", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 23
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/nvme0n1/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/259:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(25, "size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 33
openat(25, "removable", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "ext_range", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "nvme0n1p3/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p3/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(25, "nvme0n1p1/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p1/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(25, "nvme0n1p2/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p2/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sr0/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/11:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(25, "size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 33
openat(25, "removable", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "ext_range", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/11:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(34, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sr0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/11:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 35
openat(35, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/11:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 35
openat(35, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/nvme1n1/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/259:1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(25, "size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 33
openat(25, "removable", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "ext_range", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "nvme1n1p1/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/nvme1n1/nvme1n1p1/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sda/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/8:0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25
openat(25, "size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 33
openat(25, "removable", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "ext_range", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 33
openat(25, "sda2/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sda/sda2/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(25, "sda3/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sda/sda3/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(25, "sda1/size", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/block/sda/sda1/dev", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 34
```

It might be related to the fact that I have multiple disks and partitions mounted, but I don't understand why it would wait for them every time a directory is changed. I was also wondering if it maybe is refreshing the disk space used bars in the sidebar every time, but hiding all sidebars doesn't change anything.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=426672 might be related, but I don't have any docker containers running and not that many mounts (`mount | wc -l` shows 30 lines).

One more thing I just noticed: Opening a directory in a new tab is instantaneous. So really just changing the current directory is what seems to cause this delay.

Regarding DNS:

- `sudo tcpdump udp port 53 --interface wlp26s0` doesn't show any requests when doing something in Dolphin.
- `strace -e trace=network dolphin` shows a few lines, but not reliably on every single directory change:

```
recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\1T\24\0\0\0\0\277\6\0\0\5\213\367\0\314\3\16\2\314\3\16\2\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
```

(the English message is "Resource temporarily unavailable")

Comment: Does it happen with other file managers, Nemo, Nautilus, etc?

Comment: In thunar it is instantaneous and it also is in nemo and Nautilus. Also things like `cd` are also not affected.

Comment: This issue is often caused by incorrectly/slowly setup/working name resolution.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I didn't think of DNS and indeed 1 second delays in e.g. HTTP requests is something I had in the past when my primary DNS broke. But I can't find anything related here in this case (see the last edit)

Comment: Debugging ideas: you may look at the summary produced by `strace -c ...` and search for significant gaps in the timestamps produced by `strace --relative-timestamps=us ...`; plus, you should be able to get messages in English using `LC_ALL=C strace ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this KDE bug report describes pretty exactly this issue:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=442106

And it seems to be triggered by `/etc/fstab` entries with `UUID=` of devices that are not plugged in at the moment (which I have for external drives).